# .Net Framework Data Provider not found on host

Tags: .net, asp.net, mysql, entity-framework

I have a working web site using Linq to Entities, on a MySQL database.  Last night I installed the MySQL connector 6.0 for .NET, and all was good on my local machine.  I assume I now have some GAC to Bin migration to do on the host.  Does anybody know what files I must transfer and what I must do to my web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 should be installed on the host machine. 
2) Your application should have access to MySql.Data.dll and MySql.Data.Entity.dll (for example, put them into the Bin folder of your application). 
3) ADO.NET provider should be registered in the application configuration file, like this:

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
        description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" 
type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, 
Version=6.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out later on a VPC.

Answer (score 0):

Install .NET Framework 3.5 on the host.

Comment: It is installed on the host.  All the other 3.5 goodness works.